# Custom font in pdfjet android

Tags: java, android

Hi I recently downloaded the open source version of pdfjet that is offered on their website I extracted the downloaded zip and copied the java files found in the com\pdfjet folder to android studio next to my MainActivity.java. I tried a couple of examples that uses some of the corefonts and it works flawlessly but When I want to embed a custom font for the text it won't work on android studio.

I searched on the Internet for a solution but the only solution I found is this:

```
Font f2 = new Font(pdf,
            new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "fonts/DroidFonts/DroidSerif-Italic.ttf")),
            CodePage.UNICODE,
            Embed.YES);
```

From:
http://pdfjet.com/java/examples/example-07.html

But android studio output an error
like in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3SPG.png

Any possible solution?

Note: I am using the open source version and I want to use it in Android application
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Do you have your custom font is `assets` directory?

Comment: Yeah it is in my assets folder even if I change the directory to be:

getAssets.open(cfont.ttf)

it still dont work I think the error becuse of the Font.java not having a method for 4 inputs the max is 3 as shown in the image.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out it in empty project

Comment: Thank you I am waiting your reply :-)

Comment: Did it work with you or the same error was outputted?

Comment: I found  out the problem!!!!

Comment: In the open-source version of the library it is not possible to embed a custom font as I conclude because when I tried the evaluation copy of their library it worked flawlessly and the above code worked.

Comment: So is there any way for me to embed a font without purchasing a **commercial license**???

Comment: Did you find an answer? Is it possible to read `ttf` from assets?

Comment: @I33t Till now no, I am able to access the ttf font, but when I do so in pdfjet I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` event though I set the `android:largeHeap="true"` and hardware accelerated to flase but the error persists on all the fonts causing the app to crash. Any help @Taras ?

Answer (score 0):

They did change their constructor. Just remove "CodePage.UNICODE" part.

```
protected final Font getFont(String fontName, PDF thePdf) throws Exception {

    InputStream fontStream = context.getAssets().open(TypefaceContainer.getFontPathFromName(fontName));
    Font result = new Font(thePdf, fontStream, Embed.YES);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The PDF file have a Unicode Text inside, wouldn't that affect it? Also are you speaking about the free or the commercial one?

Comment: It's free one but such update should affect paid version also since they did improve library to support all encodings based on font properties. So code pages became useless. Most of properties listed in font constructors are ignored now, according to free version sourcecode.

Comment: So Does this mean it will work flawlessly with RTL language like the Arabic language?

Comment: Not exactly. There are still some issues present with language support.
Arabic-only font or Arabic-oriented (containing Arabic as primary character set) will work fine but unicode fonts (with english set as primary), supposed to support multiple character sets - won't.

The best result I was able to achieve - is Arabic + English alphabet support. For other languages I did switch fonts (based on user locale)

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of the Java file as I am unable to do so in the free version. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for delays, I don't visit SO often. I have added code sample for my font loading method

Comment: Hi I am able to access the ttf font using your method, but when I do so and run pdfjet's Font class I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError event though I set the android:largeHeap="true" and hardware accelerated to flase but the error persists on all the fonts causing the app to crash. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure about exact reason of your issue, but I would recommend you to store and re-use font instance in your app in case you don't.

Comment: The error happens on the first access of the font from the Font class, I mean android is able to access the font and use it but the Font class inside PDFJet is crashing and causing the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. If you have a working example please give it to me as my deadline is close and I am still unable to add the pdf generation to my app. Thank you a lot. @Taras <3

Comment: Such crash can be caused by incorrect asset resource access. Are you using same method as mine?

Comment: Yes the same method @Taras

Comment: Unfortunately, my current project is under NDA, so i can't share any class from it -just separate utility methods. I would recommend you to try some other fonts and older library versions.

Comment: Hi, in the commercial version of the library the fonts are saved as .stream, trying those in the open source version the app won't crash and it will generate the pdf, but how can I create a .stream of other fonts? @Taras

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try this approach.

Comment: Hi can you send me the version of pdfjet that you are using along with the sdk version maybe this might solve the issue. Thanks @Taras

Comment: Here is reference to the code I'm using. Library is modified. I have added a few features like multiline table cell support. And base library version is lower than yours.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hlF2EocXrmdiJ3dcaa2mBO7hBHiZk3Su/view?usp=sharing